# Nginx route client IP to same Worker process

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy

Reading about the Nginx architecture and this diagram from 
https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/ makes sense;

[image: NGINX master-worker architecture]

What I want to do is tell the Nginx master process to always route requests from the same client to the same Worker, by keeping a table of client IP -> Worker PID. Is there a config option to specify how Master-> Worker routing works?

For example assume the following request-> worker cases:

```
IP              Worker PID
18.234.1.200    1000
18.234.1.199    1001
18.234.1.200    1000
18.234.1.198    1002
18.234.1.197    1000
18.234.1.200    1000
```

Notice how a new client IP 18.234.1.197 can also route to Worker with PID 1000 but the 18.234.1.200 IP always will route to Worker 1000.

If there's no config option but I could write some Lua code, I already use Nginx Lua a lot so that would be possible. Some intuition on how to affect the Master->Worker selection would be awesome.

Comment: See this https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted! The difference being, I don't want to load-balance across multiple servers, but across multiple workers in the same server. I'm using `ngx.location.capture` to forward requests to a different end-point in the same server (for async), can I use `ip-hash` inside that `location` block to apply load-balancing across workers?

Comment: AFAIK it is not configurable this way for workers. You will have to probably modify Nginx source to do so. Because Lua comes inside different directives of Nginx, and there is no worker selection.